# InputStream hanging in Java Socket

Tags: java, sockets, jsf

I have a client socket which I am reusing its inputs and outputs in different methods. The problem now is I sent a string from the server and received on my client side with my input stream but I want to read this just once and continue executing my other codes as I want to leave the streams open for other methods that would send data to it in the future. But it hangs after I fetch the data. Please help. I would only want to close my stream and socket when I am ready and Im not ready to close it in that method.

```
if (myAddress.getIpAddress() != null) {

                    System.out.println("Im add WebSite from client side and my client is " + clientSocket);

                    if (clientSocket != null) {
                        System.out.println("Im add WebSite from client side and my client is not null " + clientSocket);
                        out.println("addWebSite%"+addSite);
                        out.flush();
                    }else {
                        System.out.println("Im add WebSite from client side and my client is null " + clientSocket);
                        clientSocket = new Socket(myAddress.getIpAddress(), myAddress.getPortNumber());


                         out =
                                new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

                            in =
                                new BufferedReader(
                                    new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

                            out.println("addWebSite%"+addSite);
                            out.flush();
                    }

                }

                // this gets printed out but after everything hangs
                System.out.println("I am in readLine "+ in.readLine());


                String moodSite = in.readLine();

                Sites sites = new Sites(addSite, moodSite);
                sites.setAddress(myAddress);

                 session.persist(sites);


                 session.getTransaction().commit();
            }
            } finally {
            if (session != null) {
                session.close();
            }
```

Comment: Does your try-finally block also have a catch block? Are you catching exceptions that might be occurring?

Comment: I throw my exceptions when I first create my sockets and initialize my inputs so there is no problem there

Comment: I'd guess the next `in.readLine()` after the working code has either nothing to read (check your server code) or no new-line character (`\n`) to read (check your server code). A line can also only be read once and is consumed. I see 2 readlines, but only 1 write.

Comment: yes it sends only a string and after that has nothing to read. But then how do I tell my input Im done reading for that method so move on till there is data that comes through again in the future.

Comment: what about if an exception occurs outside your control. How do you catch it? What if commit() throws an exception, how do you handle that?

Comment: At a guess the client isn't sending a line terminator, but until you post the concerned it is impossible to be sure.